# How can I access NodeHandle w/ Nodelets?

Tags: ros, octomap, ros-kinetic, nodelet, octree

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the following Nodelet onInit:

```
void OD::onInit()
{
    ros::NodeHandle& private_nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();
    ros::NodeHandle& nh = getNodeHandle();
    NODELET_DEBUG("Initialized the Nodelet (OD)");
    odom_sub        = nh.subscribe("/base_odometry/odom", 10, &OD::odomCallback, this);
}
```

Where I have declared a nodeHandle and a privateNodeHandle. If I understood correctly, a good rule of thumb is to use the nodeHandle with Topics and the Private one with Parameters.

Well, on the *odomCallback*, I want check if `nh.ok()` or if `private_nh.ok()`, as well as `private_nh.param<float>("uav_sphere_scale", scale, 1);`, but none of this work and give the error:

```
error: ‘nh’ was not declared in this scope
(...)
error: ‘private_nh’ was not declared in this scope
private_nh.param<float>("uav_sphere_scale", scale, 1);
```

On my class, *OD*, the `onInit` was declared as public and the *odomCallback* as protected.

My question is, how can I access, either the NodeHandle, or the PrivateNodeHandle on my callback function?

EDIT:
I already tried to declare the NodeHandlers *a-priori*:

```
namespace nodelet_obstacle_detector
```

{
class OD : public nodelet::Nodelet
{
public:
virtual void onInit();
ros::NodeHandle& private_nh;
ros::NodeHandle& nh;

But it shows the following error when I compile:

```
/home/(...)/nodelet_obstacle_detector.h:49:11: error: uninitialized reference member in ‘class nodelet_obstacle_detector::OD’
 class OD : public nodelet::Nodelet
       ^
/home/(...)/nodelet_obstacle_detector.h:54:30: note: ‘ros::NodeHandle& nodelet_obstacle_detector::OD::nh’ should be initialized
         ros::NodeHandle& nh;
```

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297712/how-can-i-access-nodehandle-w/-nodelets?/) by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2018-07-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
ros::NodeHandle& private_nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();
ros::NodeHandle& nh = getNodeHandle();
```

There are just local variables, that only exist within onInit(). You need to declare them in your class declaration and set them in this function. Something like this:

```
class OD
{
  ....
  ros::NodeHandle private_nh;
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  void onInit()
  {
      ...
      private_nh = getPrivateNodeHandle();
      nh = getNodeHandle();
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [kev-the-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/36226/kev-the-dev/) with karma: 81 on 2018-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-07-17**:
Hi, I had tried that before, but it when I try to compile it shows the following error:

```
 /home/(...): note: ‘ros::NodeHandle& nodelet_obstacle_detector::OD::nh’ should be initialized ros::NodeHanndle& nh;
```

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-07-17**:
So, I think that somehow I can't declare the variables w/out initializing it. I now included this attempt on my question.

**Comment by [kev-the-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/36226/kev-the-dev/) on 2018-07-17**:
Yeah that's how C++ works, all variables must be initialized in the constructor. So you can either make it not be a reference (no & in the declaration), or just use getPrivateNodeHandle() each time you want to use it. (e.g  `getPrivateNodeHandle().param<float>("uav_sphere_scale", scale, 1);`

**Comment by [jpde.lopes](https://answers.ros.org/users/34263/jpde.lopes/) on 2018-07-17**:
Understood. Thank you very much.